# Choosing between a colon and semicolon when both are appropriate

Tags: grammar, semicolons, colons

Let's say you want to write one of the following:

I am very happy; I just won $100.

I am very happy: I just won $100.

It is my understanding that both of the above sentences are grammatically correct.  How, then, would you decide which to use?  Is there a subtle difference between them?

Comment: The colon says "and here's why."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you want to say.

As stated in the comment, colon says

> and here's why, or because

so your sentence would be

> I'm very happy because I won $100.

That seems to be what you want to say, because they are correlated.

But a semicolon separates independent clauses, and can be written with a period. So you are saying,

> I'm very happy. I won $100.

So it depends on you, but 99 out on 100 cases, go with my 1st one.